# Не умею cоставлять код с функциями , посоветуйте материалы с доскональным разжёвыванием синтаксиса функции в python

Tags: python-3.x

С клавиатуры вводятся числа a и b, b > a. Найдите сумму факториалов чисел из диапазона [a; b]. Для вычисления факториала реализуйте функцию factorial(n).

Comment: _посоветуйте материалы с доскональным разжёвыванием синтаксиса функции в python_ - вы можете ТС что-то лучшее посоветовать, чем ссылка выше?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, вопрос в заголовке звучит как `"Не умею cоставлять код с функциями , посоветуйте материалы с доскональным разжёвыванием синтаксиса функции в python"`, есть соответствующий вопрос-ответ со списком ресурсов. При чем тут учебные задания?